# How to put a value from watch function into a cookie and then later retrieve it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to store some user information on first page of my application into a cookie using Angular. Here is what I am trying.

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngCookies"]);
    angular.module('aApp').controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$cookies', function($scope, $cookies) {

        var someInfo = $scope.userinfo = "";

        $scope.$watch('userinfo', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            someInfo = newValue;
            getUserInfo(someInfo);
        }, true);

        function getUserInfo(someInfo) {
            console.log("User information " + someInfo);
            var name = someInfo;

            $cookies.put("name", $scope.userinfo);
            $cookies.get("name")
        }
    }]);
})();
```

The part of setting and getting a value from cookie always shows up as undefined although the userInfo has value in it. Any suggestions why it might be happening. I read online that $watch will only look for changing value but not setting it, that is why I first read the new value and then set it in cookie but it shows up as "undefined". Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry.. I have it like this $scope.$watch('userInfo', function(newValue, oldValue). Is that incorrect?

Comment: I edited the question with what I had. So I watch `userInfo` and put the changed value in `someInfo` variable.. I am trying to set the `someInfo` value in a cookie but unable to. Thanks.

Comment: This does not use `someInfo` is this a typo? `$cookies.put("name", $scope.userinfo);`

Comment: I want to retrieve the value eventually from the scope as it will be in another part of the application. Should I though set $scope.userInfo = newValue before pass  $scope.userInfo to the getUserInfo function and then set that scope value in the cookie? I have tried that too but doesnt set it. Any help?

Comment: Seems to work just fine, although it looks like you have unused and unnecessary variables. Where do you get `undefined`?

Comment: Any updates on this?